# Deploying AKS cluster with ARM template sporadically fails with PutNetworkSecurityGroupOperation error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

I am deploying an AKS cluster using an Azure template. Most of the time deploying the AKS cluster succeeds. But sometimes, with the same inputs the deployment fails with `Operation PutNetworkSecurityGroupOperation (XXXXXXXX) was canceled and superseded by operation PutNetworkSecurityGroupOperation`. The azure template and deployment error are included below. What could cause this issue?

## Template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The resource group name."
      }
    },
    "subscriptionId": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The subscription id."
      }
    },
    "region": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The region of AKS resource."
      }
    },
    "gbPerNode": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 20,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Disk size (in GB) to provision for each of the agent pool nodes. This value ranges from 0 to 1023. Specifying 0 will apply the default disk size for that agentVMSize."
      },
      "minValue": 1,
      "maxValue": 1023
    },
    "numNodes": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The number of agent nodes for the cluster."
      },
      "minValue": 1,
      "maxValue": 50
    },
    "machineType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_D2_v2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The size of the Virtual Machine."
      }
    },
    "servicePrincipalClientId": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Client ID (used by cloudprovider)"
      },
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "servicePrincipalClientSecret": {
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Service Principal Client Secret."
      },
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "osType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Linux",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Linux"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The type of operating system."
      }
    },
    "kubernetesVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "1.11.5",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The version of Kubernetes."
      }
    },
    "maxPods": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 30,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Maximum number of pods that can run on a node."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "deploymentEventTopic": "deploymenteventtopic",
    "resourceGroupName": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
    "omswsName": "[concat('omsws-', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]",
    "clustername": "cluster"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-03-31",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters",
      "location": "[parameters('region')]",
      "name": "[variables('clustername')]",
      "properties": {
        "kubernetesVersion": "[parameters('kubernetesVersion')]",
        "enableRBAC": true,
        "dnsPrefix": "clust",
        "addonProfiles": {
          "httpApplicationRouting": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "omsagent": {
            "enabled": false
          }
        },
        "agentPoolProfiles": [
          {
            "name": "agentpool",
            "osDiskSizeGB": "[parameters('gbPerNode')]",
            "count": "[parameters('numNodes')]",
            "vmSize": "[parameters('machineType')]",
            "osType": "[parameters('osType')]",
            "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks"
          }
        ],
        "servicePrincipalProfile": {
          "ClientId": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientId')]",
          "Secret": "[parameters('servicePrincipalClientSecret')]"
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkPlugin": "kubenet"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## Error

```
{
   "code":"DeploymentFailed",
   "message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
   "details":[
      {
         "code":"Conflict",
         "message":"{\r\n \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Canceled\",\r\n \"message\": \"Operation was canceled.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Canceled\",\r\n \"message\": \"Operation was canceled.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"CanceledAndSupersededDueToAnotherOperation\",\r\n \"message\": \"Operation PutNetworkSecurityGroupOperation (XXXXXXX) was canceled and superseded by operation PutNetworkSecurityGroupOperation (XXXXX).\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: have you got any azure policies?

Comment: Yeah just one called **ASC Default**,  which seems to be autogenerated by Azure Security Center. What should I look at in the policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause seems to be deploying the AKS cluster with **httpApplicationRouting** routing enabled. To work around the issue I deploy the cluster without **httpApplicationRouting** in the template and then programmatically enable it after the cluster is deployed using the azure java sdk.

```
final KubernetesCluster kCluster = serviceManager.kubernetesClusters()
  .getByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, deploymentName);

final Map<String, ManagedClusterAddonProfile> addonProfileMap = new HashMap<>();
addonProfileMap.put("httpApplicationRouting", 
   new ManagedClusterAddonProfile().withEnabled(true));

kCluster.update()
  .withAddOnProfiles(addonProfileMap)
  .apply();
```

I opened a support ticket with Azure and the support engineer confirmed this is a bug that the AKS team is working on fixing. So there should be a resolution soon if you don't want to implement the workaround.

Comment: @Gaurav I was told by the Azure support engineer that the issue has been fixed. I haven't seen it since, but I might just be getting lucky. I suggest opening a support ticket if it's still happening for you.